# Finding images on the web

Tags: privacy, image, face-recognition

I sent someone a photo of me and they replied that this particular photo was all over the web.  How do I find out where this photo is and is there any way that I can see if there are other photos of myself that someone has shared without my knowledge?  I am very worried about this and want to find out where these pictures are please help me!

Answer (score 1):

Try a Reverse Image Search Engine, like TinEye.

http://www.tineye.com/

There's also Similar Google Images.

http://similar-images.googlelabs.com/